# Storyboard: Leading Edge constraint correct, but Center X is off the screen

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am so frustrated. Step by step directions for what I am doing:

I start with this in storyboard:
[image]

With a leading constraint:
[image]

And it shows up as expected in the simulator (ignore the different values):
[image]

Next, I try to change that constraint:
[image]

To a Center X constraint:
[image]

In storyboard it looks right:
[image]

But in the simulator it loads off the screen!
[image]

This is also true if I change it to a trailing edge constraint. I have tried the same thing on several widgets on this view. What could be causing this?

EDIT:
To simplify the scenario I removed all other views except Current Time.

These are the only two constraints:
[image]

Again, it looks right on storyboard, but its messed up on the simulator.

EDIT: I think its also worth noting that I am using a view controller inside a container view.

Comment: Looks to me like you have a clashing constraint for the Route Time which is dependent on the Current Time. Route time is pushed right on your storyboard picture but not on the simulator version. Are there no errors in the simulator console? Search for "satisfy constraint", to see if there are any issues. Would need to see the full set of constraints really.

Comment: Better to use the preview mode than the storyboard as it will show you per device layout. Also check for the view hierarchy showing a red error tag in the top right indicating constraint issues.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Thanks for the reply. See edit. I ruled out other widgets affecting it.

Comment: It could well be the container view. If you created it in storyboard you need to give it constraints to position it on screen. Just placing it in storyboard using Any/Any size class may leave it as 600 wide which would explain what you are seeing if half the container is off screen. Try adding leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints for the container view. Hopefully that should fix it.